# How to assign element from list to a variable?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my Dart code. Why doesn't it work?

```
  var myList = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
  String number = myList[0];
```

I want number value to be zero. The error I'm getting is:

```
The instance member 'myList' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expressiondart(implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)
```

Comment: you want to remove all value inside myList?

Comment: i want the variable 'list' on the second line to get the value from index 0 of myList, which is 'zero' in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use an other variable when defining other variable in initializer. try assign value to `number` in initState like this:

```
  var myList = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
  String number= '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    number = myList[0];
  }
```

Comment: Sorry I did a bad job of naming variables, I want an element of the list as a String variable. I have edited the question too.

Comment: ok, what do you mean by  `Why doesn't it work`?

Comment: flutter gives the error i put in the question (edited again).